# Consume RabbitMQ messages with order and context

Tags: java, rabbitmq

What would be the best way to consume "topic-ed" message batches from RabbitMQ in parallel and in order.

We have a server that processes data for many customers. Every time a customer's data is processed, a bunch of messages is sent to RMQ. On the other side we have a process that consumes the data and stores it in a database.

The consumption process is slow and we want to parallelize it and make it scalable. The problem is that data for a single customer cannot be processed by two consumers at the same time.
The producer runs every now and then and can add messages to the queue even for a customer that already has messages in the queue.

One of the suggestions was to create a new DB table that will indicated for each customer if it's data is being processed. A consumer will only ask for messages for customers that are not being processed by other consumers and will register itself in the DB for that customer.

I'm reluctant to use that solution because it requires connecting to a database and it holds runtime state in a database.

I was hoping to find a solution that could be handled within the scope of our consumer/producer code and RMQ.

A suggestion was made to have messages written to RMQ under customer "topics" and have the consumers read a single "topic". A message will be added to a separate queue (or "topic") for each batch or customer messages. A consumer will consumer a "customers" message and use it's data to select a "topic" from the main queue.

The problem is what happens when the producer wants to add new data to the main queue for a customer that already has data in the main queue that is currently being processed.

How can we sync the consumption an production over RMQ?

Comment: Have you tried using transactions? I have no first-hand experience with them, but it seems what you are looking for (as long as the messages originate from the same producer session)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could have a look at rabbitmq tutorials available.

http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-five-java.html

Sample code:

```
import com.rabbitmq.client.*;

import java.io.IOException;

public class ReceiveLogsTopic {
  private static final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "topic_logs";

  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
    Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

    channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, "topic");
    String queueName = channel.queueDeclare().getQueue();

    if (argv.length < 1) {
      System.err.println("Usage: ReceiveLogsTopic [binding_key]...");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    for (String bindingKey : argv) {
      channel.queueBind(queueName, EXCHANGE_NAME, bindingKey);
    }

    System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

    Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
      @Override
      public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope,
                                 AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body) throws IOException {
        String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + envelope.getRoutingKey() + "':'" + message + "'");
      }
    };
    channel.basicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);
  }
}
```

Method to execute the code and saving in a file:

```
java -cp $CP ReceiveLogsTopic "#" > logfile.log
```

I hope it helps and give you a Idea.

Actually best way is to use DB but if you are not ok with it means you can give a try by having the messages in a file and track and reuse it.

That is you can save the details in file while executing and can track it as you needed in runtime.

**Note** : I have attached the sample code given in tutorial, because anyone can track details even though if link is getting changed in future.